# What does the name Spring IO mean?

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-io

In fall 2013 Spring has launched its new Website ([spring.io](http://spring.io)) and announced its new platform "[Spring IO](http://spring.io/platform)". **But what does this name/abbreviation "IO" mean?**

*I am NOT asking for any (technical) description of what Spring IO is, I am only interested in the name.*

*This question is not about the name of the website, it is about the name of the platform! - It think names are important for programming, and good names help to understand programs faster (Clean code), so I hope this name is not only a marketing gag*

Comment: I thought it was *input/output* :D

Comment: @Maroun Maroun: this way my first idea too, but this does not have any relation to what it is.

Comment: It's a synnergry driven, paradigm breaking front burner buzzword thing I'd guess!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the name of a site, not programming.

Comment: @RossC True, it has **enterprise**, **platform** etc on it's web page. It is a new **silver bullet**.

Comment: An actual quote: "demonstrate a significant potential time-to-market advantage for building, delivering and deploying Enterprise Data Services solutions."

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: thanks for the hint

Answer (score 6):

its **Integration Objects** as given in the link http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-and-c24-io-accelerating

Comment: You mean IO refers (wrong written) to the tool: "C24 Integration Objects (iO)"?

Comment: it seems so..here is an article which reflects spring coupling with c24
http://ref.c24.biz/whitepapers/Extending_Spring_with_C24_Integration_Objects.pdf