# Where does Spring Data fit in to Spring 7 modules?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

As per my knowledge, all services provided by Spring are organized in to esven modules of spring . Here they are :-

[image]

Recently i cyame know of more services provided by Spring like Spring data ,Spring Integration, Spring Batch, Spring Securit. Are these new modules or they are one of of the part of seven main modules already provided by spring?

Comment: Spring IO stands for "integration objects": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346213/what-does-the-name-spring-io-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more up-to-date bird's eye view of the Spring IO platform is provided by the following diagram

[image: spring io platform]

You can read more about the relevant components [here](https://spring.io/platform)

The modules in the diagram you mention would all fit into the framework part of the diagram I posted, except *Web* and *MVC*

Spring Data is it's own project that of course depends on the core Framework.

An overview of the modules in the core Framework is given by the following image

[image]

Comment: What is IO here? whats the IO foundation and IO Execution ?

Comment: The whole Spring platform is now called Spring IO.

Comment: Thanks geoand. But i tried to google for - what IO stands for in Spring IO ? But did n't get my answer. Do u have any idea about it? Also i did not get Whats the difference b/'w IO foundation and IO Execution ?

Comment: You can think of foundation as the main libraries that make up the whole platform. The execution here means what ways you can actually use to make applications that use the libraries of the platform. For example Spring Boot helps you get started with a Spring application by providing default autoconfiguration. IO probably means Input Output but I am not sure :)